# Str to hex in Python

Tags: python

I receive on my socket a 4 bytes value that I want to print as hex value. I am trying:

```
 print "%08x" % (nonce)
```

However, I get an error message that string can't be converted to hex. Anyone an idea
how this could be quickly resolved?

Comment: What value does `nonce` have?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `struct` module to unpack the octets received from the network into an actual number. The `%08x` format will work on the number:

```
import struct
n, = struct.unpack('>I', nonce)
print "%08x" % n
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a string containing the bytes. However, to print them as a number you need well.. a number.

You can easily create the hex string you are looking for like this:

```
''.join('%02x' % ord(x) for x in nonce)
```

Demo:

```
>>> nonce = os.urandom(4)
>>> nonce
'X\x19e\x07'
>>> ''.join('%02x' % ord(x) for x in nonce)
'58196507'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
from binascii import hexlify
>>> hexlify('a1n4')
'61316e34'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = "9999"
print hex(int(num))
#0x270f
```

Comment: `I receive on my socket a 4 bytes value` - it's unlikely it contains just ascii digits that are usable with this

Answer (score 0):

If your data can be converted to a string, you could use the [`str.encode()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method:

```
>>> s = "XYZ"
>>> s.encode('hex')
'58595a'
```